# How to find topological properties of pre-image groups of a piecewise continuous function?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, continuity, piecewise-continuity

Let:

$$ \begin{align}
f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) &= \sin(x_1 - x_2^3) + e^{x_4-x_3^4} + \tan(x_2)\ln(x_1)-100 \\
f &: X \to Y \\
X &\subset \mathbb{R}^4 \text{ is the natural domain of } f \\
Y &\subset \mathbb{R}
\end{align} $$

Define:

$$ A = \{ \underline{x} \in X | f(\underline{x}) \lt 0 \}  = f^{-1}(y<0) $$
$$ B = \{ \underline{x} \in X | f(\underline{x}) = 0 \} = f^{-1}(y=0) $$
$$ C = \{ \underline{x} \in X | f(\underline{x}) \le 0 \}= f^{-1}(y \le 0)  $$

I want to check some topological properties of these sets.

I can see that $f$ is continuous wherever it's defined. $y<0$ is an open set, therefore $A$ is also an open set, as a preimage of an open set through a continuous function. Therefore, it can't be closed, since in an Euclidean space only the 2 trivial sets are clopen sets.

I've tried to prove something similar with B and C. The complement of $y=0$ is an open set, therefore, $B_{\neq} = f^{-1}(y\neq0)$ is an open set. But we can't conclude that B is closed, since the domain $X$ is an open set, and I assume $ B = {B_{\neq}}^c \cap X$.

1. How should I think about complement sets where the domain is not the whole space?
2. Should I be bothered by the fact that the domain isn't connected?
3. I suspect B to be not open ("1 dimensional paths in $\mathbb{R}^4$") and not closed ("$x_1=0$ contains boundary points but isn't part of the domain or B"). I also suspect the same for C. but I don't know how to prove that without going into many many details.
4. I think $A,B,C$, has the same interior, which is equal to $A$, and has the same boundary, which is not equal to $B$. Is that correct? Can we say anything else about the interior or boundary of these sets, $A, B, C$?

---

Partial answers and hints will also be appreciated.

My definitions:

- p is an **interior point** of set S if there exists an open ball centered at p which is completely contained in S
- S is an **open set** if all points in S are interior points of S
- The **interior of a set** S is the set of all the interior points of S
- p is an **accumulation point** of S if every neighborhood of p contains at least one point in S distinct from p
- S is a **closed set** if it contains all the accumulation points of S
- p is a **boundary point** of S if if every neighborhood of p contains both, at least one point in S distinct from p and at least one point not in S distinct from p
- The **boundary of a set** is the set of all the boundary points of S

Comment: The natural domain $X$ is an open set ($x_1 >0$ and $x_2 \notin \{(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2} : k \in \Bbb Z\}$ and $A$ is a relatively open subset of $X$ hence of $\Bbb R^4$ (open in open is open).

Comment: Domains of functions don't have to be connected, already $\tan$ has a disconnected domain in $\Bbb R$ or $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$; it happens a lot.